# Starting a service

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to run a simple Service that counts to from 0 to 1000 and stop.
Here is my code:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    private Timer timer;
    private int counter;
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        this.timer = new Timer();
        this.counter = 0;
        startService();
    }
    private void startService() 
    {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                MyService.this.counter++;
                if(counter == 1000)
                    timer.cancel();
            }
        },0,100);
    ;}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

And from my activity on the onCreate method I do the following thing:
    MyService service = new MyService();

My application is crashed and I get the following error:

> 01-05 16:34:28.880: E/AndroidRuntime(30183): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.location/com.example.android.location.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.location.MainActivity

**EDIT**

The manifest:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.location"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <service android:name="com.example.android.location.MyService" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.location.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it crash as soon as you try to open it? maybe you've changed the manifest or the Activity package or name, but not both? Is your activity called MainActivity and package com.example.android.location?

Comment: I load the activity and then crash, the names are correct.

Comment: I think the service is irrelevant here, it the activity that is crashing. Can you post the entire manifest (not only the application element), and either a screen capture or an ls -R of the app directory tree from the root?

Comment: I edited the post please check it, and if you mean a ss of the app it's just opening it I can see the activity for 2 seconds and then it crashes.

Comment: mmm, It all seems ok. Does it crash if you comment out the lines to start the service?

Comment: It keep crashing even when I remove the intent lines, I will just open a new project with new activity and it will work. Thanks!

Comment: I've seen this happening when renaming things, even the eclipse project, or when moving things around. Sometimes a refresh and clean does it, but I too have seen myself having to start a new project.

Answer (score 3):

> from my activity on the onCreate method I do the following thing:
>
> ```
>     MyService service = new MyService();
> ```

becuase you are trying to start an Servie by Create an Instace which is not valid way for start service.

for starting service from any Application component we have a method `startService(Intent intent)` . you can use this method for starting your service as:

```
Intent intent =new Intent(Your_Current_Activity.this,MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

and make sure you have declare your Activity and Service in `AndroidManifest.xml`  as:

```
  <service android:name=".MyService" />
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said but I keep getting this error.. why it's cant find the MainActivity class? I attached the manifest